# Strongly type a recursively nested proxy

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have some objects that I store content for some UI. They look like this:

```js
const copy = {
  header: {
    content: 'Page Header'
  },
  main: {
    header: {
      content: 'content sub header'
    }
    body: {
      content: 'lorem ipsum....'
    }
    dynamic: {
      content: (data: string) => `some ${data}`
    }
  }
}
```

I have written a proxy which lets me get an ID, generated by the deeply nested path of the content I am accessing:

```js
const isObject = (obj: unknown): obj is Record<string, any> =>
  typeof obj === 'object' && obj != null

const createHander = <T extends Record<string, any>>(path: string[]) => ({
  get: (target: T, key: string): any => {
    if (key === 'id') {
      return path.join('-')
    }
    const newTarget = target[key]
    if (isObject(newTarget)) {
      return new Proxy(newTarget, createHander([...path, key]))
    }
    return newTarget
  },
})

export const withIds = (copyObject: Record<string, any>, initialId: string) =>
  new Proxy(copyObject, createHander([initialId]))
```

so the following is true:

```js
const copyWithIds = withIds(copy, 'page')
copyWithIds.main.body.id // page-main-body
```

Trouble is, everything on the copyWithId's object is now of type any

I would *like* to not be reliant on the `any` type as the return of the `get` but struggling to find a set up that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mapped type to emulate what you are doing in the function code

```
type WithId<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: 
      T[P] extends Function ? T[P] :
      T[P] extends object ? WithId<T[P]>:
      T[P] 
} & {
    id: string
}
export const withIds = <T extends Record<string, any>>(copyObject: T, initialId: string) =>
  new Proxy(copyObject, createHander([initialId])) as unknown as WithId<T>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBKAOBPGBeGBvAUDGALApgIYAm+ATgFwbY5zhT5hRUDkACoQOb4wASRpMixoBfADQ0AtoQCWYKllp4B5BTSWgmjZjBaaGTGBACuAI2UlywpePUxTIYojVKc+7awA2IMvkkwZeBNJADowkOtaWyUnMEJJGWAXV3cmKgAKYkIoQipoMjlOAEpUAD4YAAMIEEkeABJ0LJyRCrsRUUx2zE1oAIgAeVMAK3xgWDR0kGGqYzAAazAQAHcwIqopob6YACVRn2IAHnzCsRhCMERylFKaKER4fBAAMxgN1BQ0Fg3RqBYYADJ-q9hjAAIRoMDGTyeTDdcC9YC+bL4XjnQSoGAHAAqMHwAA8DMQIDs9mRDscwJxTudLqV0vBsrg8lACpSANoAXRK1xg6UUMG4OnSOTIgqoWNOc3wziMLMKazOFzK1CUMhe6SlyA+nxkxBYJX5Sl8UGMZDAMAZUFwISGIDk6RYAFp9W07D1YGB8EssYRRfhxjARYK2ZqOXY1byZANhj90p7vb7BUUDXYcMbTeb4zA2GQQHjEHGvT6-VBToiiAxUWBBOk2eFLbhJdKuUVXUb-RmYPHi4LRBIRK27g8YAB1GRWgCShyxVxVtDZbAC5s1zxgWI5VFTa4XHNxBMYRJgADFZmMZOAYAB+bdsXcULdYnd7wnE75jK+j8e4KfYnele+uDeu6dACc44LqzKspwnSYPi8A+LA7owEsX5TsSaDYs+B7ErsoBkkccqUtSFylHSCCIIMIxjOKpxyOOMiEJ4U6QfKZQ0FmOZ5gW5GUT8ZZIpWaLkLWdFQAxTHEC2ZzErMCzLOahDEmOk7TjccKQIhIBIMp36HmgKEqRA6TkacLAMtwLrkTpaEhNIcghLE8SJCEqRQOkABE7mtkAA)

Comment: This doesn't quite work. `copyWithIds.header.content` is reporting a type of `never`

Comment: `[P in keyof T]: T[P] extends object ? WithId<T[P]> : string` seems to work

Comment: @MildFuzz it should have been `T[P]` my bad. Fixed

Comment: Almost. I have updated my example because I need to support both strings and function as content.

When I use the above, and I try to call a function I get `This expression is not callable.Type 'WithId<(data: string) => string>' has no call signatures.`

Comment: @MildFuzz you need to special case any subtypes of object that you don't want mapped through `WithId` (functions are objects) Updated the answer